# Merge statement not inserting data

Tags: sql, oracle, select

I have just started learning how to use a merge statement, but whenever I execute the procedure in which the merge is located, none of the data is inserted. Below is my code for the merge where I have created table customers_dw as a data warehouse & customers_ex_view is just a select statement for the columns I need.

```
MERGE INTO customers_dw dw
USING customers_ex_view ex
ON (dw.customer_id = ex.customer_id)
WHEN MATCHED THEN
    UPDATE SET 
        customer_id = ex.customer_id,
        first_name = ex.customer_firstname ,
        last_name = ex.customer_lastname ,
        shipping_address = ex.customer_address,  
        city = ex.customer_city,
        state = ex.customer_state,
        zip = ex.customer_zipcode,
        phone = ex.customer_phonenum,
        data_source = 'EX'
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
        INSERT (customer_id,first_name,last_name,shipping_address,city,state,zip,phone)
        VALUES (ex.customer_id,ex.customer_firstname,ex.customer_lastname,ex.customer_address,
        ex.customer_city,ex.customer_state, ex.customer_zipcode,ex.customer_phonenum)
;
```

Comment: before we dig deep, there are 2 simple options worth exploring: 1) `customer_ex_view` produces 0 rows 2) every row in `customer_ex_view` has a matching row in `customers_dw`

Comment: I executed the select statement in the view, and it is returning rows. When I created the customers_dw table I added columns, but there's not data/rows in it at all. I'm not sure what is causing the insert not to perform.

Comment: do you commit the merge? can you execute the merge outside of the stored proc and see if something gets inserted?

Answer (score 0):

Your statement is not actually executing. In the UPDATE section you're setting the value of the CUSTOMER_ID field, but CUSTOMER_ID is used in the ON clause. This is an error, and it's causing an `ORA-38104: Columns referenced in the ON Clause cannot be updated: "DW"."CUSTOMER_ID"` exception to be thrown. Remove the line in the UPDATE section which says `customer_id = ex.customer_id,` and make sure you're properly trapping and reporting exceptions.

[db<>fiddle here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=dc443471cf3ce19421a72a75408549bd)